# Prefix "emp–" (assimilated from "ent–") in "empfinden" and "empfehlen" – etymology, explanation?

Tags: etymology, prefix

Eine schwer zu googlende Frage:
Woher kommt das Präfix „emp–“? Kann man sich die Bedeutungen von *empfehlen*, *empfangen* und *empfinden* herleiten, indem man diese Verben als aus deren Stamm mit diesem Präfix zusammengesetzt betrachtet?

Dem Verweis in der Antwort von jarnbjo nach ist „emp–“ eine assimlierte Variante von „ent–“.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Die Vorsilbe *ent-* wird in einigen Fällen vor f zu *emp-* angeglichen. *ent-* hat den gleichen indoeuropäischen Ursprung wie Griechisch "*anti-"* und Latein "*ante"*. Du findest eine recht ausführliche Erklärung der Vorsilbe "*ent-*" aus dem Duden Universalwörterbuch [hier](http://www.wer-weiss-was.de/theme143/article1176994.html).

Wie bei vielen anderen Vorsilben hat "*ent-*" so viele Bedeutungen, dass es kaum möglich ist aus der Bedetung des Stammes logisch abzuleiten was "ent-"+Stamm genau bedeuten soll. Im Falle von "*ent-*" z.B. konkret, dass etwas anfängt (*entzünden)* oder dass etwas aufhört (*entbürokratisieren*).

Comment: Danke für den Verweis. Das habe ich natürlich nicht gefunden, weil ich nicht „ent-“ gesucht habe.