# "Sich empfehlen" bzw. "Ich empfehle mich" als Abschiedsformel: Ursprung und Bedeutung?

Tags: etymology, proverb

Veraltend kann man sich zum Abschied empfehlen: "Ich empfehle mich!"

Natürlich ist das nur eine Floskel, aber kann jemand etwas zur Herkunft und Herleitung sagen? So ohne Zusammenhang scheint mir das doch sehr von sich selbst eingenommen, wenn man sich anderen empfiehlt.

Comment: cf. https://german.stackexchange.com/q/29567

Comment: That's not valid German...

Comment: @somega how so?

Comment: @somega Eigenartig, ich musste das nicht erst googeln, benutze diese Wendung sogar hin und wieder und werde daraufhin nicht verständnislos angestarrt. Also stimmt mit deinem *`That's not valid German...`* vermutlich etwas nicht.

Comment: Die Redewendung stammt aus dem 18. Jahrhundert. Also ist meine Aussage bezogen auf die Gegenwart korrekt. Und im Duden habe ich es auch nicht gefunden.

Comment: @somega Unter https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/empfehlen ganz nach unten scrollen, da findest Du es.

Comment: Man kann sich auch zum Abschied empfehlen, ohne gerade zu veralten.

Comment: Die Redewendung mag alt sein, aber ich kann bestätigen, dass sie auch heutzutage noch verwendet wird

Comment: @vectory *empfehlen* hat mit *fehlen* so gut wie nichts zu tun. Siehe Pfeifersches Etymologisches Wörterbuch.

Comment: @tofro, ach wenn, die Antwort dort stünde, wär die Frage ja einfach. Aber schau selbst: [DWDS.de](https://dwds.de/wb/empfehlen) -- da steht von der gesuchten Abschiedsformel nichts. Bei Grimm steht ein Zitat unter einem anderen Punkt (s. unten) aber noch nicht, dass das der Ursprung wäre. Neuer Vorschlag: von *ab in die Falle*, altererbt, etwas umgestellt, natürlich kaum mehr nachvollziehbar

Comment: Die Formel aus dem Zitat steht so ähnlich übrigens auch unter *Grüßen*, also bedeutet es in dem Zitat eventuell schon dass (was den Beleg somit zweifelhaft macht)

Comment: ich wils yhn auch keynen danck nicht wissen, noch sie (die concilia) drumb grüszen noch von yhn begehren Luther 12, 238 W. (https://dwds.de/dwb/grüßen). Gut nicht ha'jenau dieselbe Formel, aber schon sehr ähnlich formell. Heute spricht man eher von [anrufen](https://dwds.de/wb/anrufen), oder ggf. von *bitten* bzw. *bieten*, wie in *anbieten*.

Answer (score 3):

zwar keine richtige Antwort aber zu lang für einen Kommentar:

[Grimms Wörterbuch](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?bookref=3,424,42):

> 6) sich empfehlen ist höflich grüszen, ich lasse mich ihm empfehlen,
>   lasse ihn grüszen; diese höflichkeit geht, wie der grusz, einer
>   weiteren bestellung voraus: lauf hin zu NN, sage, ich liesze mich
>   empfehlen und mich erkundigen, wie er sich befinde, er solle doch das
>   versprochne schicken.
>
> 7) da man vorzugsweise beim abschied die gunst eines andern erbittet,
>   so drückt sich empfehlen geradezu abgehen, weggehn aus: ich will mich
>   ihnen empfehlen = verabschieden; empfiehl dich! entferne dich;

Comment: Don't prove me wrong? Grimms Wörteruch sagt: 6) sich empfehlen ist höflich grüszen, ich lasse mich ihm empfehlen, lasse ihn grüszen; diese höflichkeit geht, wie der grusz, einer weiteren bestellung voraus: lauf hin zu NN, sage, ich liesze mich empfehlen und mich erkundigen, wie er sich befinde, er solle doch das versprochne schicken. 7) da man vorzugsweise beim abschied die gunst eines andern erbittet, so drückt sich empfehlen geradezu abgehen, weggehn aus: ich will mich ihnen empfehlen = verabschieden; empfiehl dich! entferne dich; http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?bookref=3,424,42

Answer (score 0):

**Ich empfehle mich!** scheint ein Abschiedsgruß aus dem 18. Jahrhundert zu sein.

Die Details kannst du [hier](https://www.helpster.de/ich-empfehle-mich-redewendung-informatives_187525) nachlesen.

Als Deutscher weiß ich, dass diese Grußform aber heute nicht mehr verwendet wird.

Heute übliche Abschiedsgrüße sind (häufigste zu erst):

- Tschüss!
- Ciao!
- Mach's gut! (Nur unter Freunden, da es ein verstecktes du enthält. (Mach **du** es gut!))
- Servus (Nur unter Freunden)
- Auf wiedersehen!
- Adieu! (Falls du etwas witzig sein willst.)

**Edit**:

Auf Englisch übersetzt würde der Satz lauten: **I recommend myself!**

Es ist quasi ein Eigenlob. Es klingt auch etwas arrogant.

Deshalb gibt es im Deutschen auch das Sprichwort: **Eigenlob stinkt.**

Comment: Gerade, da nach den "Details" gefragt wurde solltest du diese hier ergänzen. Außerdem kann der Link theoretisch morgen schon tot sein.

Comment: Auch der Fragesteller weiß, dass diese Redewendung nicht mehr verwendet wird. Von daher gehen die heute üblichen Formulierungen und erst recht die englischen Ausdrücke an der Frage vorbei.

Comment: Dann verfasst halt eine besser Antwort ;) Ich kopier hier bestimmt nicht einfach den Text von der Quelle nach se...

Comment: Hallo Somega, danke für Deine Mühe. Den Link bei Helpster habe ich auch schon gefunden, halte ihn aber nicht für sonderlich belastbar. Ansonsten geht Deine Antwort leider nicht wirklich auf meine Frage ein.

Comment: Selbstverständlich wird das heute noch verwendet. Nicht so oft im Alltag wie das flapsige "Tschüss", aber zu etwas offizielleren Gelegenheiten kann man das durchaus hören, und im privaten Bereich auch gerne mal mit ironischem Unterton. Und als Eigenlob wird das ganz und gar nicht empfunden, eher als leicht antiquierte Floskel.

Comment: Also ich persönlich habe es noch nie gehört. Und weil ich davon ausgegangen bin, dass der Fragesteller kein Deutscher ist, habe ich halt gesagt, dass diese Grußform veraltet ist. Sonst verabschiedet er sich an der nächsten Tanke noch mit "Ich empfehle mich!". Und ich denke, da sind wir uns einig, dass die Kassiererin dann ganz schön blöd schauen würde.

Answer (score 0):

Das ist mmn. ein anderer Weg auszudrücken : Ich bin ihnen stets zu Diensten. Also sehr höflich und nicht von sich eingenommen.